# Need some contrains, but seem unable ro configure it in xcode interface builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have two controls vertically placed

I have an UIImageView a top. I may at runtime resize this in height to better hold he image inside (this is my own code that resize) - below that I have an UITableView which should fill height.

I have set UIImageView constraints to left:0 (superview), top:0 (superview), right:0 (superview) - I have not set a bottom constraint since there is none. it could be whatever it takes.

However, some problems with UITableView though...

When I try add constraints for UITableView (spacing to nearest neighbor) and select the top, it force enters the height of the UIimageView (here 107 pixels, but that height changes at runtime, so it should not use that). That appears to be wrong. I want spacing to be 0 to nearest neighbor, not 107 from top, so already here I fail at setting up a meaningful constraint

Am i missing something obvious? I am new to ios/xcode so it is very likely

Anyhow, currenly I am getting these warnings:

> Frame for outlet tableview" will be differen at runtime

and

> height is ambigious for outtlet main logo

If it not possible tto define align/constraints/fill I want, I guess I could simply do it runime? The calculation should be pretty simple? But would sill like to get rid of warnings then.

**Update**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give height constraint for your imageView. For tableView give vertical spacing to your imageView with appropriate constant (0 if you don't want any spacing between them). And give bottom:0 (superview) for your tableView along with left and right. That should get rid of those warnings. Now you can change `constant` property of height constraint for imageView at runtime and tableView height will be changed automatically. To change constraint at runtime create `IBOutlet` for that particular constraint and change constant property of the constraint.

**EDIT**

[image: Constraints]

Comment: Like this?: uiimageview top=0 left=0 right=0 heightconstraint<=600 ----- uitableview left=0 right=0 botttom=0 ----- vertical-space-constraint wth first-item = uitableview.top relation=equal uiimageview.bottom ---------- I now get "height and vertical positions are ambigious for uitableview" and "height is ambigious for uiimageview" ---------- I guess the warnings are correct can be ignored if I change min-constrain and max constraint runtime for uiimageview? (note: adding a min constraint for uiimageview seems to confuse designer)

Comment: (Thanks!) But why am I with this: "uiimageview topconstraint=0 leftconstraint=0 rightconstraint=0 heightconstraint=200 height=200 ----- uitableview leftconstraint=0 rightconstraint=0 botttomconstraint=0 height=400 ----- vertical-space-constraint wth first-item = uitableview.top relation=equal uiimageview.bottom" ----- getting errors "frame for uitableview will be different a runtime" and "frame for uiimageview will be different at runtime"? I would think that with above constrains, interface builder should have no designtime warnings left? :)

Comment: I have added screenshot, it seems to work fine for me. Can you please verify if constraints you have added are same?

Comment: Added screenshot now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102098/discussion-between-vishnu-gondlekar-and-tom).

Comment: Problem is with your misplaced frames. If you add constraints to margin there has to be some padding(20 px) between view and subview. Since you have given constraints to margin it says your frames are misplaced as there is no padding. All you have to do is either remove "relative to margin" or update your frames

Comment: It works now without errors after fixing what you said there. I did not know tthat padding was a requirement, but I have added it back :)